# How to check if file exists and create new file in C

Tags: c, file, raspberry-pi

I am new to programming in C and I am programming for the Raspberry Pi using a C compiler. All I want to be able to do is create a function that takes a String as a parameter and save it as a text file in a specific location. I want to check that file location to see what files exist and save the new file to that folder with an increment of 1 added to the file name.

For example, folder contains:

TestFile1
TestFile2

And I want to be able to create the new file saved as TestFile3.

This is the code that I have so far and want to know if I am on the right lines and get any tips please:

```
void WriteToFile(unsigned char *pID)
{
printf("Writing to file. . . . .\n");

/* Checking to see how many files are in the directory. */
int *count = 0;
DIR *d;
struct dirent *dir;
d = opendir("table_orders");
if(d)
{
    while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
        count = count + 1; // Adds 1 to count whenever a file is found.
    }
    closedir(d);
}

char str[sizeOf(count)]; // Creates string.
sprintf(str, "%d", count); // Formats count integer into a string.

File *f = fopen("table_orders/Order " + str + ".txt", "a"); // Creates new file.

if(f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}

fprintf(f, "Order: %s \n", pID);

fclose(f);

printf("The Order %s has been written to the file\n", pID);
}
```

Comment: A simple google would answer your question.

Comment: I know but I have tried that and didn't find what I wanted and I'm not sure what the best thing to search would be. What would you suggest?

Comment: `File *f = fopen("table_orders/Order " + str + ".txt", "a");` you cannot concatenat strings like that in C. `char str[sizeOf(count)]; ` and count is a pointer to int, not an int.

Comment: I could possibly use DIR to search a directory. Is it possible with that function to get the amount of files that are in the directory?

Comment: When putting numbers into strings like you are it makes much more sense to precede numbers with 0 to make them say all 4 character spaces wide. Also read man pages for fopen, it creates empty new files with usual flags.

Comment: You're a bit off all over, there's a mixture of semantic errors and bugs. You maybe need to take a step back get a beginners book or tutorials to get your c good, your answer is close but miles off.

Comment: Yeah I am a beginner to C, so that probably would be best thank you. I just created the function from what I thought it might be from looking at FILE functions. I predominantly program in Java so this is quite different.

Answer (score 5):

```
int fd = open( "filename", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644 );
```

Nothing else is atomic - another process can create the file in between any check for existence and your actual creation of the file.

Comment: I am sorry but I haven't come across O_RDWR, O_CREAT and O_EXCL before. What do they mean? I just tried searching them but couldn't find any clear definitions other than they are Linux access modes for files.

Comment: @JamesMeade: It means RTF manpage by invoking the shell command `man 2 open`.

Comment: I understand what these mean now, I just found good definitions for them. I will try that out thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) ([`_stat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx) in Windows) to see if a file exits. If it fails with `errno` set to `ENOENT` then the file doesn't exist. [`access`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) is another possibility.

Of course it's not atomic, some other process could create the file in between your check and your call to `fopen`.

Comment: `open(O_CREAT | O_EXCL)`.

Comment: @EOF O_CREATE etc aren't well supported by the fopen in the buffered FILE protocol

Comment: @rhubarbdog: `int fd = open(filename, access | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, mode); FILE *fp = fdopen(fd, mode);` There, was that so difficult?

Comment: @EOF Don't aim your reply at me, cos I know how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You are close, but so far off the mark, I think you need to put this on hold. Read some c tutorials with structured examples.
You have an algorithm error when you read through the directory and arbitrarily increase count. The logic should be more like
     parse dir->name to 3 tokens "Testfile" 0001 ".log"
     Using atoi or similar convert the numeral string to an int

When you declare str there's a lack of understanding of sizeof, it should read more like
    char str[25];
This is enough to hold all digits of a 4 byte int as a string. sizeof count will be 4 probably,4 bytes 32 bits.

When you fopen you do something like "Dir/file" + str + ".log"
This isn't how you do this, + is mathematical in c. You need to use strcat or sprintf into a new work string, created and freed on the fly.

When appending a number to a file like here it makes sense to precede short numbers with 0 s .  This produces regular filenames which have a good ls order.

Should you need to control create and exclusivity, you'll need to use open to open the file and fdopen it to a FILE type file handle.

When you go live with this you will need to prevent another process causing timing errors with scheduling use semaphores or a ".lock" file.

You will also want some maintenance routine to delete old logs and subsequently renumber all the remaining logs from 001

PS don't know why the down votes